# How do I start a Camel route with .autoStartup(false)

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to start a Camel route using ".autoStartup(false)". 
for example:

```
from("file:E:/Example").routeId("myRoute").autoStartup(false)
                    .to("file:E:/Example2");
```

I'm using

```
cc.startRoute("myRoute");
```

to start my route. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Almost correct but you should use the id of the route, you set with `routeId`, eg `myRoute` so it should be

```
camelContext.startRoute("myRoute");
```

Also as gtonic points out you can start routes in other ways as documented in the Control Bus EIP: https://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html

Comment: Right Claus, but in my example I used routeId=1 and here I forgot to change :/.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a pattern for this: use the [ControlBus](https://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html) to start/stop your Camel routes.

E.g.:

> template.sendBody("controlbus:language:simple", "${camelContext.stopRoute('myRoute')}");